# dynamically including source file in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to dynamically include a source file. the source file is called file.c and I'm trying to include it this way:

```
#define dot ".c"
#define file "file"
#define include_file file dot

#include include_file
```

I'm getting the following error:
**"extra tokens at end of #include directive"
"fatal error: file: No such file or directory #define file "file"**

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish with this?  This seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: Note 173 in C 2018, regarding `#include` directives with macros that are replaced says “Note that adjacent string literals are not concatenated into a single string literal (see the translation phases in 5.1.1.2);
thus, an expansion that results in two string literals is an invalid directive.”

Comment: `Thanks.` for what? Why are you writing that here? Do you have  a question to ask? Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [questions checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 2):

Note that including `.c` files is a bad practice. Including a result of macro expansion is a very rarely considered with no real usefulness. I have never worked with a code base where the filename to be included would be created from two tokens - usually a single token is used [only to alias](https://github.com/rbgirshick/dp-dpm/blob/master/external/boost/preprocessor/slot/counter.hpp#L23) the name of the source file to be included for easier typing. If you are in need for more preprocessing features, consider using other preprocessors, like `m4`. Strongly consider writing simple, easily maintainable and clearly understandable code that will be easy to find bugs in, expand and to work with for you and for others rather then writing convoluted ways to include source files.

String literal concatenation is not run over `#include` things. So do not pass string literals - but rather invoke stringify in preprocessor after concatenating your arguments. But there's yet another problem - a dot `.` can't be a part of a valid preprocessor token, so you can't `macro##.string`, you may work around that by expanding the macros on the caller part. The following seem to work:

```
#define EXP(...)   __VA_ARGS__
#define STRING(x)   #x
#define XSTRING(x)  STRING(x)
#define dot   .c
#define file  file
#define include_file  XSTRING(EXP(file)EXP(dot))
#include include_file
```